# can't queue two audio tags

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I am trying to play two sounds so the first one is played, then the second one.

I tried to search online, but it didn't help since the question isn't common and/or it is hard to phrase it both informative and short.

I did this, but of of course this didn't help and it played the two audio files at the same time.

```
<audio autoplay src="sound_1.mp3">
<audio autoplay src="sound_2.mp3">
```

### Edit

It would be very useful if instead of making a queue, you silence the second audio until the first one is finished. But a normal queue works too.

Comment: google "playlist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an **[ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event#:%7E:text=The%20ended%20event%20is%20fired,cancelable%20and%20does%20not%20bubble.) event**, by using that you can play the next audio.

```js
const audio_1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
audio_1.play();
audio_1.onended = function() {
  const audio_2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
  audio_2.play();
};
```

```html
<audio id='audio1' src='sound1.mp3'>
<audio id='audio2' src='sound2.mp3'>
```